# Using slice() method on Array like Object

Tags: javascript

I'm confused with the output.

```
var arrLike = {0:'Martin', 1:78, 2:67, 3:['L', 'M', 'P'], length: 4};
```

If I use `slice()` on `arrLike`:

```
var newArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(arrLike, 0);
```

Output:

```
console.log(newArr);
["Martin", 78, 67, Array[3]]
```

How does this happen? I can't wrap up my head around with the output.

Comment: What would you expect the output to be? That looks like exactly what slice(0) does.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Preface: Note that the `Array[3]` in your console output is just how the console is showing it to you. Your `newArr` is really:

```
["Martin", 78, 67, ['L', 'M', 'P']]
```

---

It happens because that's how `slice` is defined. Loosely speaking it:

1. Creates a new, empty array
2. Reads the `length` property of what you give it
3. Loops through from the starting index (default `0`) to the ending index (default `length - 1`); call the loop variable `k`

   1. Puts any property found in the object when asking it for property `k` into the array at index `k - start`.
4. Sets the `length` of the returned array to `k - start`.
5. Returns the array

Or (again very loosely):

```
function slice(start, end) {
    var n, k, result;
    start = arguments.length < 1 ? 0 : +start;
    end = arguments.length < 2 ? +this.length : +end;
    result = [];
    for (var k = start, n = 0; k < end; ++k, ++n) {
        if (n in this) {
            result[n] = this[k];
        }
    }
    result.length = n;
    return result;
}
```

[All the gory details](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.slice).

Since your `arrLike` object has a `length` property and has properties with the names `0`, `1`, `2`, and `3`, you get the result you've shown.

Comment: Very intuitive. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check out the spec for [`slice()`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/Ecma-262.pdf). The `slice()` function will default the `end` parameter, which you did not specify, to `this.length`, and...

> 7. If end is undefined, let relativeEnd be len; else let relativeEnd be
>      ToInteger(end).

Therefore, you're only pushing the first 4 non-element properties of the `arrLike` object into the new array.

Try using...

`var arrLike = {0:'Martin', 1:78, 2:67, 3:['L', 'M', 'P'], length: 6, 4: 'test'};`

Comment: *"...and will use that value if it's typeof is === 'number'"* No, it will use it if it's a number **or** it can be *converted* to a number (specifically, a [length value](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-tolength)).

Comment: *"Therefore, you're only pushing the first 4 elements..."* As opposed to what? There **are** only four things that can be called "elements" in it. The fifth thing (`length`) isn't an "element," it's a non-element property ("element" being the term we [and the spec] use for properties that have a name that fits the definition of an "array index").

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you, +2 and +1 for your answer.  I have updated my answer to reflect your comments